# MKDocs Can't make document

Tags: python, python-3.x, mkdocs

I will use `MKDocs` to make the document but it says:

```
Error: MkDocs encountered an error parsing the configuration file: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "/home/phao/桌面/python/Bayesian/mkdocs.yml", line 4, column 15
```

I had pushed the contents in [github commit `e8221fc1f0402834b6db92280e67e9fcac4a2b10`](https://github.com/penghao123456/Bayesian/commit/e8221fc1f0402834b6db92280e67e9fcac4a2b10) in Commits on Oct 23, 2022.
How can I finish it? Why it failed?

P.S. This is `/home/phao/桌面/python/Bayesian/mkdocs.yml`:

```yaml
site_name: Bayesian v0.1 Documentation
plugins:
  - mkdocstrings
      handlers:
          python:
            setup_commands:
              - import sys
              - sys.path.insert(0, "..")
```

And [this is the issue in Github](https://github.com/penghao123456/Bayesian/issues/1).

Comment: The problem could be the directory name `桌面`. Can you try this in a dir without the ch characters?

Comment: I thought I'd tell the developers at MkDocs about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is yaml format error. Correct format like this:

```
site_name: Bayesian v0.1 Documentation
plugins:
  - mkdocstrings:
      handlers:
          python:
            setup_commands:
              - import sys
              - sys.path.insert(0, "..")
```